# How to handle a non select dropdown menu in selenium with dynamic class value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I try to handle a dropdown menu to click on the 'Popular' option within this [website](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszU1MFDLTaywNTIAMpIrbT391JKBRJBaga2hWnqabVliUWZqSWKOWm6yrVp-EhDbpqQWJ6uVl0THAlWAKSMAxOAYsg==) using selenium, but no one example which I found doesn't suit for that.

```html
    <select class="select__select--2gOcq explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT">
    <option value="desc__" selected="">Highest User Rating</option><option 
    value="desc__discount_percent">Discount</option><option value="asc__price">Price: Low to High</option><option value="desc__price">Price: High to Low</option><option value="desc__ratings_count">Popular</option></select>
```

Have used CSS, Xpath and Select, but the result is the same: No such element.
Bellow you can see attempts and outputs.

Any ideas what I do wrong?

**CSS Selector**

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.select__select--2gOcq.explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT')

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".select__select--2gOcq.explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT"}
```

**Xpath**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[starts-with(@class,"select__select--2gOcq")]')

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[starts-with(@class,"select__select--2gOcq")]"}
```

**Select**

```
Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='select__select--2gOcq explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT']"))

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='select__select--2gOcq explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT']"}
```

**UPDATE:**

After executed the code bellow the element was successfully located but, I have caught the `TimeoutException`.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
try:
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@class, 'select__select--') and contains(@class, 'explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--')]"))))
    select.select_by_visible_text('Popular')
    select.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME? Have you tried adding a wait?

Comment: @JeffC, sure, I tried use time.sleep() and wait, but actually results is the same

Comment: @QHarr, https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwrL4mOtTVUKwdRRgAgBwRK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the *dropdown* is based on `<span>` and `<div>` nodes so you can't use `Select` *class* and to click on the option **Popular** with in the [website](https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszU1MFDLTaywNTIAMpIrbT391JKBRJBaga2hWnqabVliUWZqSWKOWm6yrVp-EhDbpqQWJ6uVl0THAlWAKSMAxOAYsg==) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11jNVy83MszU1MFDLTaywNTIAMpIrbT391JKBRJBaga2hWnqabVliUWZqSWKOWm6yrVp-EhDbpqQWJ6uVl0THAlWAKSMAxOAYsg==")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'responsiveDropdownMenu__title--')]//following::span[starts-with(@class, 'responsiveDropdownMenu__label--')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'responsiveDropdownMenu__menu--')]//a[@id='desc__ratings_count']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: vivino]

Comment: Thanks, your code looks quite intuitive.
I used `XPATH` that you got, but unfortunately the output for me is `TimeoutException`.

`select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@class, 'select__select--') and contains(@class, 'explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--')]"))))`
`select.select_by_visible_text('Popular')`
`select.click()`

Comment: @G_V Can you update the question with the exact error you are seeing as I have provided the code only to locate the select element, clicking an option will be next step.

Comment: @G_V Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have the actual html but you could try using one of the multi-valued classes or even reversing the class order. Examples (these both work when testing on html sample):

```
.explorerSortMenu__explorerSortPopoutMenu--3pMwT.select__select--2gOcq
```

or

```
.select__select--2gOcq
```

Comment: Yep, it work for the sample, but not tailored for real page. I sent the url above. Thanks

Comment: I sadly can't view that url. What error are you getting when running with actual page using selector as in my answer?

Comment: The same issues: _No such element_.
I suppose, the code that @DebanjanB provided is correct, but need to find out the right way to click()

Comment: does the selector find the element if you enter the selector in the search bar of the browser elements tab? F12